# At what $a$ is $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{ax}-e^x-x}{x^2}$ finite? What is that limit?

Tags: limits, exponential-function, fractions

Here is a function:

$$\frac{e^{ax}-e^x-x}{x^2}$$

In which $a$ is a coefficient. The problem whats us the value for $a$ which gives a finite value for the limit,

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{ax}-e^x-x}{x^2}$$

How to find that value? I first though that the degree of the numerator must be equal to that of the denominator. but I don't know what the definition of degree is for $e^x$.

Even if I knew, I couldn't find the limit.

Comment: Hint: L'Hospital's Rule!

Comment: Hint: use Taylor expansions

Comment: @ArpitKansal I think l hopital will not work there because after differentiating first time the limit is not of form in which L hospital can be applied.

Comment: Dear @AakashKumar: what if $a=2$?

Comment: @ArpitKansal It will give you $\frac{-1}{x} $ and can you apply L hospital to $\frac{1}{\rightarrow 0}$ .i.e $\rightarrow \infty $

Comment: Dear @AakashKumar,After differentiating once you'll get $\frac {ae^x-e^x-1}{2x}$.Now as the limit is finite  and denominator goes to zero so numerator should also go to zero as $x \to  0$.Hence $a=2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**. One may recall that, as $u \to 0$, by the Taylor series expansion one has,
$$
e^u=1+u+\frac{u^2}2+O(u^3).
$$ Can you take it from here?

Comment: It led me to zero regardless of what $a$ is. Better to carry it out yourself.

Comment: You get $
\frac{e^{ax}-e^x-x}{x^2}=\frac{1+ax+\frac{a^2}2x^2-1-x-\frac{x^2}2-x+O(x^3)}{x^2}$ that is $\frac{a-2}{x}+\frac{1}{2} \left(a^2-1\right)+O(x)$.

Comment: The limit is finite *iff* $a=2$.

Comment: That $O(x^3)$ was confusing me. I neglected it. yes. it'll be 2.

Comment: Are you Ok with what I wrote? Thanks.

Comment: I have found the solution myself what should I do now? delete the question?

Comment: Dear @AHB I think you should not delete because there are already good answers.You may also post your solution if its different from available solutions here!

Comment: @AHB No, do not delete it. One of the points of this website is that what you found useful may turn out to be useful to others in the future.., If you are satified with an answer, accept it ($\color{green}\checkmark$ on the left of the answer).

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

As $e^y=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\dfrac{y^r}{r!}$

$$e^{ax}-e^x-x=1-1+x(a-1-1)+x^2\cdot\dfrac{a^2-1}2+\text{terms containing higher powers of }x$$

Comment: @Olivier, thanks for your observation

Answer (score 1):

Applying once L'Hôpital yields $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{a e^{ax}-e^x-1}{2x},$$ which *can* be finite *only if*  the numerator tends to $0$, *i.e.* $a=2$. Another application, with this assumption, shows that the limit is finite *iff* $a=2$.

Answer (score 0):

While Appreciating others' answers, with the help of Olivier Oloa, I post my own solution.

$$e^{ax}=1+ax+\frac{a^2}{2}x^2$$

$$e^{x}=1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^2$$

$$\frac{e^{ax}-e^x-x}{x^2}=\frac{(a-2)+(\frac{a^2}{2}-1)x}{x}$$

We want a finite limit, so $\frac{a^2}{2}-1=1$ and $a-2=0$.
Which both lead to $a=2$.

Evaluating the limit again with known $a$,

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{2x}-e^x-x}{x^2}=\frac{1+2x+2x^2-1-x-\frac12x^2}{x^2}=\frac{(2-\frac12)x^2}{x^2}=1.5$$